# Kali live Usb booting int grub

Tags: kali-linux, usb, grub

I am kinda new to linux. I have tinkered with it an made a parrot os Live USB.
I wanted to make myself a kali linux usb so i downloaded the live iso used Rufus to flash it and set persistence partition size. It flashed correctly and i restarted my pc selected the flash drive
from the boot menu and Grub showed up and i don't know how to make it boot

Comment: Please read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/. Kali is not a regular operating system, it is a tool for professionals. If you are new to Linux you really shouldn't be using Kali. Just use a normal Linux: _any_ Linux system can do everything Kali can do you just need to install the relevant tools. And note that all we can see in that picture is you, not the text on your screen.

Comment: sorry . I didn't really know how to take the picture without the reflection

Comment: Fair enough, but we just can't read that :/. You can try transcribing the text but really, Kali is designed for experts, so if you don't know how to solve things like this, that is a strong indication that you shouldn't be using Kali. It's just not made to be used as a regular operating system. You might want to read [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360).

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** - traditional workflow for flashing Kali w/Rufus not supported with new images. Checkout new [documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-windows/#creating-a-bootable-kali-usb-drive-on-windows-etcher) on kali website. This is what worked for me:

- Use Rufus portable
- Make sure you Run as Administrator. Just do it.
  [image]
- When you get to here, select **No**
- Under advanced drive properties do the following:
  [image]
- In off chance you only have the option to use NTFS you must reformat your USB using Windows Partition wizard (see very bottom for details)
- Click **START**
- Next, select **DD mode**
  [image]
- If you get a prompt about downloading libraries from the internet due to incompatibilities do NOT, I repeat, do NOT download them. If you've followed these steps that prompt will not show

Comment back here if that doesn't fix the error. Give us a picture of the error.

Here was the troubleshoot process I did to figure out this solution:
Yesterday I experienced this issue. I've done this a million times before in years past, for some reason it wasn't working this time around. I tried everything and looked far and wide for answers. Even though I followed all the steps on all guides it STILL was not operating correctly.

I luckily had an old USB drive lying around with Kali installer and was able to boot into that just fine. This helped me validate that the issue was not hardware. It therefore must have been an issue with the flash process involving Rufus. So I played around with the settings a little bit, deviated one way or another from the guides until it worked. Morale of the story - never give up and stick to your guns.

**NTFS Format fix**
Lastly, if you get are unable to format to **Large Fat** and stuck on say NTFS you will have to first format your USB to exFAT. You will have to use the Windows Partition wizard for that... To get there press Windows Key and search for "create and format hard disk partitions"
[image]